# React Native Error - Can't find variable: self

Tags: node.js, react-native, isomorphic-fetch-api

After adding a node module,`isomorphic-fetch`(version : ^2.2.1) in React Native app, I am getting an error of `Can't find variable: self`. 
 Here I have attached a screenshot.

[image]

The error is thrown from the file, located at node_modules > isomorphic-fetch > `fetch-npm-browserify.js`. 
 Following is the code of that file.

```
// the whatwg-fetch polyfill installs the fetch() function
// on the global object (window or self)
//
// Return that as the export for use in Webpack, Browserify etc.
require('whatwg-fetch');
module.exports = self.fetch.bind(self);
```

Answer (score 6):

@Nirav Dangi,按新建fetch-npm-react-native.js 的方式在我的项目里面没有起作用； 
我这边处理方式，是直接修改，node_modules > isomorphic-fetch > fetch-npm-browserify.js 文件的返回：

> Google Translate:
>   @Nirav Dangi, in accordance with the new way fetch-npm-react-native.js in my project which is not working; I am here to deal with direct changes, node_modules> isomorphic-fetch> fetch-npm-browserify.js file Back:

```
var globalObject = typeof self === "undefined" ? global : self;
module.exports = globalObject.fetch.bind(globalObject);
//module.exports = fetch;
```

Comment: I am not good enough with the Chinese language. So far I understood by your code, it should work. Also, If you can see in my answer, I have just updated it and added  #4 `npm install`.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue with the help of this answer, 
 https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/pull/80

> Specify a separate entry point for React Native that export React
>   Native's fetch() polyfill.

1. Create an empty file named `fetch-npm-react-native.js`. Drop this file at `node_modules > isomorphic-fetch` location.
2. Add this line of code `module.exports = fetch;` to  fetch-npm-react-native.js  file.
3. Goto the file `node_modules > isomorphic-fetch > package.json`. In the `package.json` file, add `"main": "fetch-npm-node.js",` line of code.
4. Open Terminal, GoTo app directory and write `npm install`
5. Reload the app and here you go...

Ofcourse the credit goes to [Jou](https://github.com/jou)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the problem is with 'isomorphic-fetch' package

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the other solutions didn't work for me.

What I did was to replace

```
import 'isomorphic-fetch'
```

with this:

```
import 'cross-fetch'
```

This is based on the following:
https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch/issues/125